# Package ‘RODBCext’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Tags: r

I am getting the following error in R after upgrading. How should I resolve?

> package ‘RODBCext’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Comment: try to install that package install.packages('dplyr', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org')

Answer (score 3):

I installed it using following which solved my problem.

```
install.packages('RODBCext', repos='https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01/')
```